# WindowsError trying to get directory listing with os.listdir()

Tags: python, operating-system

Trying to list files in a directory:

```
H:\Photos\images\6811957
```

When I run my script:

```
print "Files in path",os.listdir(direc)
```

I get a syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:\Photos\images\read_RGB.py", line 34, in <module>
print "Files in path",os.listdir(array)
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'H:\\Photos\\images\\6811957\n/*.*'
```

Is there a quick fix? Not sure why the added characters are occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `\6` is causing an issue here. I just tried printing the path in IDLE and I got this.

```
>>> print('H:\Photos\images\6811957')
H:\Photos\images811957
```

Try doing the following when defining the path value

```
>>> print(r'H:\Photos\images\6811957')
H:\Photos\images\6811957
```

Added `r` before path to treat it as a raw text.

Comment: That worked. Will highlight as correct answer once the time limit expires.